Unexpected behavior when combining mapped type created from Union that is used within conditional type
I came across some unexpected behavior when trying to expand mapped type I created from an union of object types, when trying to use this type within conditional type: Playground
export type CompErrors = {
    type: "compilation_errors"
    val: number
}

export type TestErrors = {
    type: "test_errors"
}

export type TestInfo = {
    type: 'test_info'
}

export type Entities = CompErrors | TestErrors | TestInfo

I create a Type that transform union of object types into and object type where keys are matching type property's value.
This works as expected, and when used as function parameter I am forced to fill all the keys.
type EntityMap<Type>
    = {
    [T in Extract<Type, { type: string }> as T["type"]]: ((par: T) => any) | string | boolean | object
}

type Params = EntityMap<Entities>

const entityMapFn = (params: Params) => {}

// missing test_info prop makes error only here
entityMapFn({
    compilation_errors: "",
    test_errors: "",
})

Next I want to expand this type to change the result type based on condition, I add a boolean check and since this branch is not hit in ParamAlternative type I expect that the resulting type will be exactly the same as in case of Params type above.
This is not the case though, and while I still have an auto-completion with correct types for resulting object, now I don't need to provide all the properties in the object, since the resulting object type is different than in previous case.
type EntityMapAlternative<Type>
    = Type extends boolean ? string : {
    [T in Extract<Type, { type: string }> as T["type"]]: ((par: T) => any) | string | boolean | object
}

type ParamsAlternative = EntityMapAlternative<Entities>

const entityMapAlternativeFn = (params: ParamsAlternative) => {}

//no error for missing prop
entityMapAlternativeFn({
    compilation_errors: "",
    test_errors: (te) => {te.type},
})

I was wondering whether the condition doesn't somehow affect the mapped type below it, so I tried to make a type where conditional type is processed outside of next attempt.
This however yields the same result:
type EntityMapExtracted<Type>
    = Type extends boolean ? string : EntityMap<Type>

type ParamsExtracted = EntityMapExtracted<Entities>


const entityMapExtractedFn = (params: ParamsExtracted) => {}

//no error for missing prop
entityMapExtractedFn({
    compilation_errors: "",
    test_errors: (te) => {te.type},
})

type ParamsExtractedWithBool = EntityMapExtracted<boolean>

const withBool = (params: ParamsExtractedWithBool) => {} 

// just check that this accepts only string nothing else
withBool("string accepted")

What exactly does cause this behavior, that changes the result type even though a branch with boolean condition is not hit?
How can I make this work as intended?

Both your attempts are accidentally making it a distributive conditional type. To fix it, make it [Type] extends [boolean] ? string : ⋯ instead of Type extends boolean ? string : ⋯. See the linked q/a for more information.

Thank you, for fix and some extra explanation I got from linked answers of yours. I did not expect this behavior, I knew about disabling distribution with [] but this was to far from only simple example in docs for handling union types on arrays, which was the only thing I sued it for so far.
